# Redirigir a una página con AJAX nada más cargar la página

Tags: laravel, ajax, laravel-5

Buenas noches hoy parece que no tengo el día. Lo que estoy haciendo es cuando abro mi página con un `onload` hago que se ejecute un AJAX mandando una id que tengo en un `input hidden`. Así de este modo me dirija a la página que quiero, pero me devuelve 404 todo el rato.

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        buscarOferta();
    };
    function buscarOferta(){
        var campana=document.getElementById('campana_id').value;
        var url = '/buscaCampana';
        $.ajax({
          headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
          type: "GET",
          dataType: "json",
          url: url,
          data: {'campana': campana},
                beforeSend: function(){
                  //$("#laGrafica").html("<div id='loader'></div>")
                },
                success: function (resultado){
                    console.log(resultado.campana);
                    //location.href = '/promocion';
                    var urlPara = "{{ route('web.verCampa',":id") }}";
                    urlPara = urlPara.replace(':id', resultado.campana);
                    window.location = urlPara;
                    
                },
        });
      }
</script>
```

Como podeis ver cuando cargo la página ejecuto `buscarOferta()` que lo que hace es mandarle el parametro que tiene aquí:

```
<input type="hidden" id="campana_id" value="{{ $campana->id }}">
```

Luego lo que hago con el `success` es montar el `route` para que me lleve a esa página con esa ID.

**Tengo esto en mi archivo de rutas:**

```
Route::get('/promocion/{$id}', "Web@verCampana")->name('web.verCampa');
```

**Y en mi controlador esto:**

```
public function verCampana($id)
{
    $campana = Campana::findOrfail($id);
    //dd($campana);
    return view('verCampana')->with(['campana' => $campana]);
}
```

No se si estoy interpretando mal esto pero no hay forma, todo el rato error `404`.

Comment: yo uso esto: `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {`

Comment: en lugar del  `window.onload = function() {`

Comment: el error 404 quiere decir que no se encuentra la ruta que buscas; antes de redirigir; tienes que comentarlo y hacer el debug de los datos de la ruta que estas enviando... incluso si es posible crea la url de forma manual u fijate que exista al menos...

Comment: tambien debes validar cual es el valor del campo campana_id tiene o no tiene valo, validalo en el html de lado del navegador.

Comment: Lo he validado todo, tanto la ruta como el campo `campana_id`. No se en mi pensamiento es como un blog cuando abres por la id o por un slug, pero la diferencia al hacerlo con AJAX algo estoy haciendo mal

Comment: la url pareciera estar mal si no es en el mismo servidor esa url esta mal formada en el ajax... debes validar ese request debe tener esta construcción  `type: "POST",
            url: "directoryo/script.php"`

Comment: Tenés mal definido el parámetro de la ruta laravel `{$id}` va sin el signo $

Comment: Tienes toda la razón @porloscerrosΨ justo por eso fallaba, no se por que me dio por ponerlo así, no tengo ni idea. Buen tan simple y ya funciona. Si quieres poner una respuesta la marco como correcta!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema lo tienes al definir el parámetro de tu ruta:

```
Route::get('/promocion/{$id}', "Web@verCampana")->name('web.verCampa');
```

Pues le has agregado un signo `$`, que no están permitidos según se explica en la documentación [Route Parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-parameters).

> Los parámetros de ruta siempre se incluyen entre llaves `{}` y deben constar de caracteres alfabéticos. Los guiones bajos (`_`) también son aceptables en los nombres de los parámetros de ruta.